C++ Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 was not found
I'm starting to learn C++; but I'm getting this issue when running a helloworld app.
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   MSB8036 The Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution".    finnware.rocks  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsSDK.targets    46      


But, I have it installed.


There is likely something else going wrong here. Your best bet is to use the command-line to try build your project and look at the detailed output. You can also do this in Visual Studio via: Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build And Run. Set *MSBuild project build log file verbosity" to "Detailed".

I'm starting to learn C++; -- Someone starting to learn C++ really shouldn't get involved in Windows SDK programming, as that requires knowledge of C++ already.  Something tells me you created the wrong type of C++ project.

@PaulMcKenzie I have a simple hello world program.... When I launch it it says windows sdk.

@avery -- You should post your error as text, not as an image.  First, it is very hard to read, but second and most importantly, the image cannot be entered into a search engine to see what possible solutions exist.

Your project has selected a specific version of the SDK - why? A common choice is to use "latest installed version", unless you have a very specific reason not to.

Do other SDK versions have the same problem?

Please try uninstalling the SDK.
Then install Windows SDK from the link and select the corresponding version in the project properties, for example 10.0.26100.0:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/
